# dart - How can I resolve 'The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyUser'.'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a simple signup page. The following is my main.dart code:

**main.dart**

```
void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser>.value(
        value: AuthService().user,
        initialData: null,
        child: MaterialApp(
          home: Wrapper(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I am seeing this error on the `initialData: null,` line:

`The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyUser'.`

This is my MyUser class:

**user.dart**

```
class MyUser {
  final String uid;
  MyUser({this.uid});
}
```

It is showing me the following error on uid in line 3:

```
The parameter 'uid' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
```

I am fairly new to flutter development so I'm not sure what this means and how to resolve it. I wasn't able to find any relevant help online. Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

The entire **auth.dart** file:

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  MyUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    return user != null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<MyUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
    //.map((FirebaseUser user) => _userFromFirebaseUser(user));
    .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }


  // sign in with email and password
  Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  // register with email and password
  Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString()+"oollala");
      return null;
    }
  }

  // sign out
  Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Error in:**

```
Stream<MyUser> get user {
  return _auth.authStateChanges()
  .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}
```

It is showing me an error in `_userFromFirebaseUser`

`The argument type 'MyUser? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyUser Function(User?)'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined your property `uid` as a non-nullable `String` but it is declared as an optional value in your constructor because of the `{}` which means that it would have the default value `null` if not assigned.

To fix this error you either need to make `uid` non optional in your constructor:

```dart
MyUser(this.uid);
```

Or to make it a required parameter:

```dart
MyUser({required this.uid});
```

If it is intended that your `uid` can be `null` then you need to declare your variable like this:

```dart
final String? uid; // this is a nullable String variable
```

Comment: thank you! this solved the error in user.dart, but not in main.dart. What should I assign to `initialData`?

Comment: You are not forced to set initialData it is an optionnal parameter, if you want an initial data you could declare it like this: initialData: MyUser(/* my_user_id*/)

Comment: it wasnt the case when i made a project last time, however now it is showing me an error, not a warning, to add initialData parameter: `The named parameter 'initialData' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.` I'm not sure why there is a change now...

Comment: Okay just checked the documentation and you are right `initialData` is required, what I've said is still valid though you can assign this parameter like this: `initialData: MyUser(/* my_user_id */)` or you can type your `StreamProvider` with `<MyUser?>` so you can assign the `initialData: null`

Comment: thank you so much! this removed the error. i accidently edited your answer, i meant to edit the question.
In edit1 of my question, there is a new error i cant figure out. Could you possibly help me with that?

Comment: Your error seems to come from your `map(_userFromFirebaseUser)` because it expects your method `_userFromFirebaseUser` to be like this: `MyUser _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user)` but you will also need to change your method so it won't return a nullable value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234189/discussion-between-hek18-and-guillaume-roux).

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have provider 5.0.0
and then change your `main.dart` to

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser?>.value(
      initialData: null,
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```